# Domain provider doesn't provide a way to wildcard CNAME subdomains. Is there something I can do to make this happen?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record

So I bought a domain and tried to setup a CNAME for all subdomains (*). Unfortunately, it only lets me CNAME the root(?) domain. I tried talking to customer support, but they were no help. Is there a way I can go about doing this? Is there a way I can have another company host my domain?

Domain is locked for transfer until 60 days after I bought it.

Comment: Use different nameservers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Would that allow me to change the DNS settings? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Well if you host with your own name servers you can configure your zone however you like.  As for the exact method, it depends on the registrar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your registrar and your DNS provider can be different companies.

If you can change just the NS records to point to another provider (such as Route53 or DynDNS for example) then your registrar will not be hosting your DNS any more.  Your registrar *should* take care of the glue records for you but may not.  It will still work if they don't but may be less efficient.

You will have to set up an account and all the other records at the new DNS provider before making the NS change unless you like downtime.  You can make wildcard CNAME records at most providers.

The cost should be low.  Route53 costs us about $0.51 per month for a low traffic domain.

After your 60 days are up, follow Wesley's advice.  Transfer away and tell them why you're leaving.

---

As a side note, you should not be able to make a CNAME record at the root.  Nonetheless, I have seen providers which allow this.  It doesn't end well.

Comment: Thanks! I'm moving to DNSimple because it's what Heroku recommends. I don't mind the downtime since it's just a sample application I made for my portfolio.
What are glue records?